# I get an error of traceback (most recent call last) when I try to run this Python program. I want to know the solution to this

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial, xbee

This is a Python program to receive the data from an XBee module using the *python-xBee* library. I have installed both the `xbee` and `pyserial` modules.

```
import serial
from xbee import XBee

serial_port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
xbee = XBee(serial_port)

while True:
try:
    print xbee.wait_read_frame()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   break

serial_port.close()
```

But when I run this and any kind of program with serial port, this is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Manurajeev/PycharmProjects/untitled/one.py", line 4, in
<module>
    serial_port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 31, in
__init__
    super(Serial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 240, in
__init__
    self.open()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in
open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}:
{!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port '/dev/ttyUSB0':
WindowsError(3, 'The system cannot find the path specified.')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't understand what the problem is. I tried everything, but the same error keeps popping up every time.

Comment: `'/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600` that's not how you specify path in Windows. And so is the error telling you `serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port '/dev/ttyUSB0': 
WindowsError(3, 'The system cannot find the path specified.')`

Comment: I also got the same error when I use 'COM' port instead of '/dev/ttyUSB0'

Comment: Show more the log.

Comment: serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM5': WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.')   This is what I get when I use COM port

Comment: raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'          //This is what I get when I run it in raspberry pi

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, check the permissions on the tty device (`ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0`) to ensure that you have read/write access to it.  Note that it might have a different name.

For Windows, have you been able to open `COM5` with a terminal emulator and send/receive data on the XBee?  Do you still have it open in another program when you're trying to open it in Python?  Only one program can access a COM port at a time.